# If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$, are the following statements known to hold in general?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, perfect-numbers

(Note: This question has been cross-posted from [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207537).)

Let $\sigma$ be the classical sum-of-divisors function.

A number is said to be *perfect* if $\sigma(N)=2N$.

If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$ (i.e., $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$), are the following statements known to hold in general?

> (a) $\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$ is *large*.
>
> (b) The deficiency $D(n^2) = 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)$ is *large*.
>
> (c) The *index* $i(q^k) = \sigma(N/q^k)/q^k$ is *large*.

Using the *trivial* relationships:

$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = \frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})} = i(q^k) = \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}$$

then if the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture that $k = 1$ is true, it is possible to show that a lower bound for the quantities (a), (b) and (c) is given by $n/\sqrt{3}$.  (Here, I have used [Acquaah and Konyagin](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S1793042112500935)'s estimate $q < n\sqrt{3}$. The inequality $q^k < n^2$ then gives the desired *large* numerical bound if we use known lower bounds for the odd perfect number $N = q^k n^2$, latest of which are by [Ochem and Rao](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2012-81-279/S0025-5718-2012-02563-4/).)

What happens when $k > 1$?  I do know that
$$\frac{\sigma(N/q^k)}{q^k} = \sigma(n^2)/q^k \geq 315$$
by using a result of [Broughan, Delbourgo, and Zhou](http://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf).

Is it possible to do better than this, apart from attempting a proof of (*obviously*) $q^k < n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$.

In a recent preprint, Brown claims a complete proof for $q < n$, and a partial proof that the inequality $q^k < n$ holds under many cases.  (See [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591).)

In particular, since $q \leq q^k < n$ holds if Brown's proofs are correct (and *completed*), then the resulting lower bound is
$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = \frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})} = i(q^k) = \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} > \frac{8}{5}\cdot\frac{n^2}{q^k} > \frac{8}{5}\cdot{n}.$$

<s>Notice that Brown's proofs hold unconditionally (i.e., even if $k=1$).</s>

We then have the desired **large** numerical lower bound
$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = \frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})} = \frac{\sigma(N/q^k)}{q^k} > \frac{8}{5}\cdot{n} > \frac{8}{5}\cdot{{10}^{500}},$$
which is an easy consequence of [Ochem and Rao's](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2012-81-279/S0025-5718-2012-02563-4/) $N > {10}^{1500}$ and the inequality $q^k < n$.